# Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF3, Package failed updates

Tags: powershell, windows-store-apps

I notice there are a number of similar errors to this one.
However note the HRERULT code = 0x80073CF3
And this this is an error preventing me from deploying my app to a tablet, something I have been previously able to do.
This error comes up when running powershell to install my application.

### The full error message is as follows;

Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF3, Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.

Windows cannot install package  because this package depends on another package that could not be found. This package requires minimum version 12.0.21005.1 of framework Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00 published by any publisher to install.

### C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\12.0

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the developer mode in your tablet? 
Do it by: Settings > Update & Security > For Developers, check developer mode or sideload apps..

This should fix the problem..

Comment: The tablet uses windows 8.1 and this solution can only be applied for windows 10.

Comment: You have to have a developer license in your machine though, can you please confirm that by running this command in your PowerShell: 'Get-WindowsDeveloperLicense' .

Comment: I renewed it yesterday

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: ```PS C:\Users\Yerong\Downloads\Ubuntu> Get-WindowsDeveloperLicense
ExpirationTime      IsValid
--------------      -------
9999/12/30 18:00:00    True```